# Issue with double quote and quotes

Tags: javascript, onclick, escaping, double-quotes, single-quotes

I am creating a list of links in javascript but it appears that the browser are translating some caracters

This is my code

```
vLinea += "<a href='#' onclick='window.open('frmEnviarPorCorreo.aspx?Pr_Id=" + pData.Pr_Id + "'"
vLinea += ", '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=no,status=no');>"
vLinea += "<img   class='imgShare'  src='images/icoEmail.png'>" 
vLinea += "</a> </li>"
```

What I would like is this

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('frmenviarporcorreo.aspx?pr_id=12806','_blank','location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=no,status=no');"><img class="imgShare" src="images/icoEmail.png"></a>
```

What I am getting is this, Some `'` are translated as `"` some `"` are added I don't know why

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open(" frmenviarporcorreo.aspx?pr_id="12806'," '_blank',="" 'location="yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=no,status=no');"><img class="imgShare" src="images/icoEmail.png"></a>
```

Comment: `'window.open('frmEnviarPorCo....` you cannot use nested quotes... use escaped double quotes `'window.open(\"frmEnviarPorCo....`

Comment: I think it works for both single and double quotes in js

Answer (score 0):

You need escape character() if you want to add a quote mark in the middle of the same kind of quotes without terminating the string. I think the only escape you need is on the first row just after "window.open, to not terminate the onclick quote just before you want to give it the path.

```
vLinea += "<a href='#' onclick='window.open(\'frmEnviarPorCorreo.aspx?Pr_Id=" + pData.Pr_Id + "'"
vLinea += ", '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=no,status=no');>"
vLinea += "<img   class='imgShare'  src='images/icoEmail.png'>" 
vLinea += "</a> </li>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the escape for your quotes:

```js
vLinea += "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.open(\'frmenviarporcorreo.aspx?pr_id=\'" + pData.Pr_Id +"\'"
vLinea += "\',\'_blank\',\'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=no,status=no\');\">"
vLinea += "<img class=\"imgShare\" src=\"images/icoEmail.png\">"
vLinea += "</a> </li>"
```

The escape works for single or double quotes.